Bizarre Compile Error: cannot convert type to itself
I program with NDI SDK 5, and I got a very bizzare compile error when trying to use some of the library fonctions.
platform : MSVC
audio.NDI.ixx :
export module audio.NDI;

export import :finder;

audio.NDI-finder.ixx
export module audio.NDI : finder;

#include "Processing.NDI.Lib.h"

import <vector>;


/**
 * @brief Encapsulation of ndi finder object
 */
export class ndi_finder
{
private:
    NDIlib_find_instance_t finder;

public:
    /**
     * @breif constructor with default options
     * show_local_sources = true;
     * p_group            = nullptr;
     */
    ndi_finder();

    
    /**
     * @breif constructor with options
     * @param show the list of NDI sources that are running on the local machine?
     * @param groups to search in for sources.
     */
    ndi_finder(const bool, const char*);
    
    ~ndi_finder();

    /**
     * @breif search for all NDI sources available.
     * @param search timeout.
     * @retrun available source list.
     */
    auto find_source(std::size_t) -> std::vector<NDIlib_source_t>;
};

audio.NDI-finder.cpp
module;

#include "Processing.NDI.Lib.h"

module audio.NDI : finder;

import <stdexcept>;

constexpr auto NDI_TIMEOUT = 1000;

ndi_finder::ndi_finder()
{

    NDIlib_find_create_t findCfg{};
    finder = NDIlib_find_create_v2(&findCfg);
/*  a copy of signature : 
    PROCESSINGNDILIB_API
    NDIlib_find_instance_t NDIlib_find_create_v2(const NDIlib_find_create_t*   p_create_settings NDILIB_CPP_DEFAULT_VALUE(NULL));
*/

    if (!finder)//nullptr in case of failure.
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create NDI finder !");
}

ndi_finder::ndi_finder(const bool show_local_sources, const char* p_groups)
{
    NDIlib_find_create_t findCfg;
    //configure finder
    findCfg.show_local_sources = show_local_sources;
    findCfg.p_groups = p_groups;
    findCfg.p_extra_ips = nullptr; //deprecated feature

    finder = NDIlib_find_create_v2(&findCfg);
    if (!finder)//nullptr in case of failure.
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create NDI finder !");
}

ndi_finder::~ndi_finder()
{
    NDIlib_find_destroy(finder);
    /*  a copy of signature : 
    PROCESSINGNDILIB_API
    void NDIlib_find_destroy(NDIlib_find_instance_t p_instance);
    */
}

auto ndi_finder::find_source(std::size_t ndi_timeout) -> std::vector<NDIlib_source_t>
{
    
    const      NDIlib_source_t* sources {};
          std::uint32_t         source_number {};
               bool             found {false};
          std::size_t           ndi_timeout{};

    //try to find sources
    while (!found)
    {
        NDIlib_find_wait_for_sources(finder, ndi_timeout);
        /* a copy of function signature
        PROCESSINGNDILIB_API
        bool NDIlib_find_wait_for_sources(NDIlib_find_instance_t p_instance, uint32_t timeout_in_ms);
        */

        sources = NDIlib_find_get_current_sources(finder, &source_number);
        /* a copy of function signature
        PROCESSINGNDILIB_API
        const NDIlib_source_t* NDIlib_find_get_current_sources(NDIlib_find_instance_t p_instance, uint32_t* p_no_sources);
        */

        found   = true;
    }
    if (source_number == 0)
        throw std::runtime_error("No source found.");
    else
    {
        std::vector<NDIlib_source_t> sources_found(sources, sources + source_number);
        return sources_found;
    }
}

then I get serveral error, they are all related with NDI SDK library functions and they are all some kind of type conversion error. What makes me confused is that, they are trying to claim that the compiler cannot convert a type to itself.
Error   C2440   '=': cannot convert from 'NDIlib_find_instance_t' to 'NDIlib_find_instance_t'       
Error   C2440   '=': cannot convert from 'NDIlib_find_instance_t' to 'NDIlib_find_instance_t'       
    
Error   C2664   'bool NDIlib_find_wait_for_sources(NDIlib_find_instance_t,uint32_t)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'NDIlib_find_instance_t' to 'NDIlib_find_instance_t'

Error   C2664   'const NDIlib_source_t *NDIlib_find_get_current_sources(NDIlib_find_instance_t,uint32_t *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'NDIlib_find_instance_t' to 'NDIlib_find_instance_t'
    
Error   C2664   'void NDIlib_find_destroy(NDIlib_find_instance_t)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'NDIlib_find_instance_t' to 'NDIlib_find_instance_t' 

I have no idea why compiler tries to convert a type to itself and fails. After several searches I didn't get any information useful.
Thanks for your helps!

you are looking at a summary. You need to find where you can see the complete error message output and read that

I suspect problem is use of #include "Processing.NDI.Lib.h". I'm not familial with modules yet, but check this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/modules#Importing_modules_and_header_units #include should not be used in a module unit  ....

MSVC has a known limitation that if something is both #include'd and imported, it sees them as different things.

@MarekR well, so I must modularize any third-party lib before use it in my own module ?

What version of VS are you using? I believe they fixed it in latest preview.

@Osyotr Its Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current Version 17.9.6

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

@hu4nghe I understand this that when your translation unit is exporting a module then compiler is assuming that content of a header included into this module should be exported too. Basically you have to do something to prevent exporting content of this header into your module.
